# IF on PHP mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a server based Sistem so users can put their money into a magnetic card (I get the ID from the magnetic card and make operations via PHP and MySQL)

The sistem works fine, I'm only missing the comparative so that I dont substract more money from the user than he actually has I thought a PHP if once I got the values, but it doesnt work I dont know why, can anybody help me?

heres my code

```
    <?php
$numero  = $_POST["numero"];
$monto   = abs($_POST["monto"]);
$monto   = -$monto;
$con     = mysqli_connect("localhost", "usrname", "PASSWD", "TABLE");
$usuario = $_POST["username"];

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysql_query($con, "SELECT Clientes.Nombre, sum(Mov_ctes.Movimiento) FROM
    Clientes NATURAL LEFT JOIN Mov_ctes WHERE cliente_id=$numero");
$row    = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if ($row[0] > $monto) {
    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO Mov_ctes(Cliente_id,Movimiento,Fecha)
    VALUES($numero,$monto,NOW())");
    mysqli_close($con);

    echo "<h1>carged  $" . abs($monto) . "  to client </h1>";
}

?>

   <a href='u.php?username=<?php echo $usuario; ?>' style='text-decoration:none;'><input
    type='button' value='Menu principal' style='width:120px; height:30px'></a>
```

tx in advance!

Comment: your code is vulnerable to a sql injection, consider to use prepare staments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this -

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Clientes.Nombre, sum(Mov_ctes.Movimiento) as sum_amount FROM
Clientes NATURAL LEFT JOIN Mov_ctes WHERE cliente_id=$numero");
$row    = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if ($row['sum_amount'] > $monto) 
{
```

Also as spotted by @Hanky - change `mysql_query` to `mysqli_query`

Comment: thank you very much!! the code works!! I dont really get why it works with an allias but thanks alot!!